# Variable assignment does not assign to variable - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, koa2

I'm performing a variable assignment in a non-asynchronous function, but the value of the destination variable does not change after the assignment statement runs.

`ctx` is a Koa2 context. This code runs once a http response has been received. I'm trying to update the context with the values from the (http) response object.

Neither `ctx`, nor `ctx.response` is frozen.

I expect `ctx.response.status` to equal `200` in the 'AFTER' console.log

I suspect that this is idiosyncratic Node behaviour, but I don't know Node very well.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
console.log('BEFORE=ctx.response.status='+ctx.response.status+'/response.status='+response.status)
  ctx.response.status = response.status
console.log(' AFTER=ctx.response.status='+ctx.response.status+'/response.status='+response.status)
  ctx.response.timestamp = response.timestamp
  ctx.response.body = response.body
```

[This was my output. Note the BEFORE/AFTER tags:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia4ph.png)

```sh
BEFORE=ctx.response.status=404/response.status=200
 AFTER=ctx.response.status=404/response.status=200
```

Comment: What is `ctx.response` ? If it's a proxy, you cannot change the value that easily. I highly doubt the problem comes from NodeJS, as assignments are not async, unless you make them so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this issue was caused by a preceding middleware call `next()` being made *without an* **await** *keyword*

I'm no expert at Node or Koa, but from research it appears that there are conditions were the status property becomes immutable.